# requests.exceptions.SSLError: certificate verify failed

Tags: python, python-requests, django-2.0

Estou tendo um grande problema com o requests do Django. Nos ultimos meses fiz um upgrade pra versao 2.0 do Django, e estou atualizando todas as libs.

Notei que isso impactou em diversos scripts que eu tinha, principalemente os que conversam com https. Por exemplo, meu PushNotification parou de funcionar, meu script que faz download de imagens de redes sociais parou de funcionar e tudo mais. Para todos esses erros recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='yt3.ggpht.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /a-/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXj-k-no (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

Segue minha versão do requests:

```
requests==2.18.4
```

Nesse exemplo em especifico, é eu tentando fazer o download de um avatar do **Youtube**.

## EDIT

Segue um trecho do código. Eu tentei usar o `verify=False` mas não adiantou, fora que não é recomendado, o próprio warning avisa..

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
import requests

response = requests.get('https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Tn306TYaqpw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAHOw/XsdeQ5H6Bds/s176-nd-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no/photo.jpg', verify=False)
yt_avatar = ContentFile(response.content)
```

Tentando com o `verify=False` o retorno de erro é diferente mas significa a mesma coisa..

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma de tentar contornar erros ligados a HTTPS dentro da lib requests é usar o parâmetro `verify` e salvar seu valor como `False`.

Como no exemplo da [documentação](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification):

```
>>> requests.get('https://kennethreitz.org', verify=False)
<Response [200]>
```

Se isso não resolver seu problema, por favor, poste um trecho do código que permita a comunidade testar localmente e identificar assim a melhor solução.

Comment: Então, fiz o teste e só recebo um warning dizendo que não é recomendado.. Mas não funciona, o retorno é diferente mas é o mesmo significado...

Comment: Qual sua versão do python? 
Se for 2.x, de uma olhada [aqui](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/223).

Comment: Minha verrsão é 3.x